# Adding add scroll down and issue in extra spacing and padding

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingTop="16dp"
tools:context="com.shubham.splashscreenemulation.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<GridView android:id="@+id/gridView" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="0dp"
android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
android:scrollingCache="true"
android:smoothScrollbar="true"
android:clipChildren="true"
android:alwaysDrawnWithCache="true"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:columnWidth="100dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"

    />
```

[Problem 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3s47y.jpg)

How do I add scroll down feature to my app so that entire text is visible?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.shubham.splashscreenemulation.MyDialog">

<ImageView

    android:src="@drawable/ahmedabad"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Details: "
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Gallery"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:onClick="closeDialog"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Famous Places"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:onClick="closeDialog2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2" />
```

[Problem 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wL03M.jpg)

I don't know exactly what happened and why these extra spacing and padding, however when I run GridView as separate activity works fine. I have tried most of the solutions with similar problems in other stackoverflow questions but none worked!

Please help!
Please tell me what files I need to upload. And please don't be rude as I have just started learning android.

Comment: add your code as well, which is creating this ambiguity.

Comment: Please specify exacly which files?

Comment: xml of both images.

Comment: @JunaidHafeez Added.

Answer (score -1):

> How do I add scroll down feature to my app so that entire text is visible?

To make the TextView scrollable, put it inside of a `ScrollView`

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
                android:text="@string/hello_world"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

> Problem 2

In your child layout, you used the `layout_height` as `match_parent`. Replace it with `wrap_content`

Comment: Solution for problem 1 has worked scrolling but I have one more question that I have added two buttons below the details and now they are appearing with the image so how do I place buttons the details and now the textview has taken up the entire screen!